# What is the most common element in the human body?

Tags: organic-chemistry, elements

I was wondering that since H2O was 66% of the human body, hydrogen would be the most. But apparently carbon is. Can someone explain that?

Comment: You have to clarify what you mean by most, whether that means number of atoms or by mass percentage. @JacobLee

Comment: And you could take most of the water out of a human body and still have a body (a dead one, admittedly).

Comment: I don't think a lack of clarity on atomic vs mass % is sufficiently unclear that the question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 5):

No, carbon is not the most common element of the human body.  [The human body is mostly water](https://www.usgs.gov/special-topic/water-science-school/science/water-you-water-and-human-body?qt-science_center_objects=0#qt-science_center_objects), so the most common element is bound to be hydrogen or oxygen.

Which one wins depends on the rules of your game.  If you are counting atoms in all those $\ce{H2O}$ molecules, you choose hydrogen.  If you go by mass instead, oxygen is the most common element in our bodies.